Paired bootstrap test p-value formula in binary classification
Background
For a binary classification task, let $M(A, Z)$ denote an evaluation metric, such as accuracy, for classifier $A$ and test examples $Z.$ Then, let
$$
\delta(Z) = M(A, Z) - M(B, Z)
$$
denote the difference in performance between classifier $A$ and $B.$
A typical null hypothesis is
$$
H_{0} : \delta(Z) \leq 0
$$
which means classifier $A$ is not better than classifier $B$ with respect to the evaluation metric that we chose [1][2]. Then, the p-value is the following conditional probability
$$
P(\delta(Z) \geq \delta_{z} | \delta(Z) \leq 0),
$$
where $\delta_{z}$ denotes the observed performance difference on the test examples $z$ that we possess.
Bootstrap
The paired bootstrap test takes $z$ and samples with replacement to create bootstrapped test examples $z_{i},$ and requires the performance difference  to be computed $\delta(z_{i}) = \delta_{i},$ where $i=1,\dots,b$. Then, the test specifies the p-value by
$$
\frac{1}{b} \sum_{i=1}^{b} \mathbb{1} (\delta_{i} - \delta_{z} \geq \delta_{z}),
$$
where the formula is described in section 2.2. of [1] and specified in section 4.9.1 of [3].
Question
The appearance of the p-value in the paired bootstrap test resembles an unconditional probability, where we measure the probability of the event $\{ \delta(Z) \geq \delta_{z}\}.$

How is this formula taking into account the conditioning event $\{ \delta(Z) \leq 0 \}$, wherein we assume that null hypothesis is true?

From past experience with conditional probabilities, I'd expect the formula to have a numerator and denominator, where the former counts some joint condition and the latter counts a single condition.
